# Changing size of terminator from command line

Tags: shell, gnome-terminator

My wish is that I would have the ability to enlarge and reduce the size of the terminal (I use `terminator`) at will. For example, that by giving the command `resize 600-400`, I can resize my `terminator` window.

Is it possible? And if `terminator` is not capable of it, is there any other terminal that can do that?

Comment: xterm does this, and some versions of VTE support it (though lacking documentation, determining *which* version is a task left to the reader).

Answer (score -1):

There are [control sequences](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html) that can change the size (and placement) of a terminal, e.g.

```
alias term-norm='printf "\033[8;24;80t"'
alias term-tall='printf "\033[8;0;80t"'
```

or in detail

```
ESC [
     Control Sequence Introducer (CSI  is 0x9b)
```

...

```
CSI Ps ; Ps ; Ps t
          Window manipulation (from dtterm, as well as extensions).
          These controls may be disabled using the allowWindowOps
          resource.  Valid values for the first (and any additional
          parameters) are:
            Ps = 1  -> De-iconify window.
            Ps = 2  -> Iconify window.
            Ps = 3  ;  x ;  y -> Move window to [x, y].
            Ps = 4  ;  height ;  width -> Resize the xterm window to
          given height and width in pixels.  Omitted parameters reuse
          the current height or width.  Zero parameters use the dis-
          play's height or width.
            Ps = 5  -> Raise the xterm window to the front of the stack-
          ing order.
            Ps = 6  -> Lower the xterm window to the bottom of the
          stacking order.
            Ps = 7  -> Refresh the xterm window.
            Ps = 8  ;  height ;  width -> Resize the text area to given
          height and width in characters.  Omitted parameters reuse the
          current height or width.  Zero parameters use the display's
          height or width.
            Ps = 9  ;  0  -> Restore maximized window.
            Ps = 9  ;  1  -> Maximize window (i.e., resize to screen
          size).
            Ps = 9  ;  2  -> Maximize window vertically.
            Ps = 9  ;  3  -> Maximize window horizontally.
            Ps = 1 0  ;  0  -> Undo full-screen mode.
            Ps = 1 0  ;  1  -> Change to full-screen.
            Ps = 1 0  ;  2  -> Toggle full-screen.
...
```

Comment: In a quick check, terminator does not respond to any of the window-change operations.